# How to read and printout hexadecimalt address type of data from a trace file(.t file)

Tags: c, scanf, fopen

I'm trying to read data from a trace file that has data, this is the first 5 lines from trace file:

W 0x7fff6c5b7b80

R 0x7fff6c5b7c48

W 0x7fff6c5b7b88

R 0x7fff6c5b7c20

W 0x7fff6c5b7b90

.

.

.

Here is the part of the code I have for that, here I'm trying to read the first 5 lines and print them out:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main ()
{
        // line buffer
        FILE *fp;
        char type;
        unsigned int address;
        
        fp = fopen("XSBENCH.t", "r");
        if(!fp)
        {
            printf("file not found\n");
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i<5; ++i)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%c %x", &type, &address);
            printf("%c %x \n", type, address);
        }        
        return 0;
}
```

This is the exact output I get:

```
W 6c5b7b80

 6c5b7b80
R 6c5b7c48

 6c5b7c48
W 6c5b7b88
```

As you can tell, its not reading in the data properly, How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

It seems `unsigned int` in your environment doesn't have enough width to store the data.

The data will fit in `uint64_t`, so using it will resolve the problem.

Also the newline character is read to `type`. Adding whitespace to `scanf` format means it will skip whitespace characters (including newline character), so it will be helpful.

More points are you shouldn't use `NULL` as file pointer to read from and you forgot to close the file.

Try this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>


int main ()
{
        // line buffer
        FILE *fp;
        char type;
        uint64_t address;
        
        fp = fopen("XSBENCH.t", "r");
        if(!fp)
        {
            printf("file not found\n");
            return 1;
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i<5; ++i)
        {
            fscanf(fp, " %c %" SCNx64, &type, &address);
            printf("%c %" PRIx64 " \n", type, address);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: it only reads W 7fff6c5b7b80 instead of W 0x7fff6c5b7b80

Comment: @PravallikaKastala My code successfully **reads** `W 0x7fff6c5b7b80`, separates it into character and integer, and prints them in [my test](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MNThZWn8jN5Eu8mE). Now it is unclear what you want. If you want to store exact lines, you should use `fgets()`.